# sendmail using incorrect timezone

Tags: sendmail, timezone

I have sendmail running on my CentOS server. The server is set to BST and tzdata is correct.

```
$ date
Tue Jul  2 10:53:56 BST 2013
$ ll /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 28 17:07 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London
```

I have a bash script running on this server which sends mail through a cronjob. The cronjob is set to run everyday **at 7am**.

```
00 07 * * * sh /root/check_mail_process.sh
```

The log `/var/log/cron` shows that the server runs the job at specified time.

```
Jul  1 07:00:01 ukibimon01 crond[15407]: (root) CMD (sh /root/check_mail_process.sh)
```

The `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` has the following settings:

```
# time zone handling:
#  if undefined, use system default
#  if defined but null, use TZ envariable passed in
#  if defined and non-null, use that info
#O TimeZoneSpec=
```

Also, no TZ variable is set on this machine.

The sendmail uses smart relay.

I also use smart relay to send mails to an **Exchange server**.

```
# "Smart" relay host (may be null)
DSexchange_server_address
```

The problem is, I receive the mail **an hour later at 8am**. The header information from Outlook is here:

```
Server (TLS) id 14.16.324.0; Tue, 2 Jul 2013 07:00:13 +0000
Received: from BY2PRD0411HT003.namprd04.prod.outlook.com (IP) by
 BY2PRD0411HT005.namprd04.prod.outlook.com (IP) with Microsoft SMTP
```

So, somehow sendmail is getting time from somewhere else and using

Answer (score 1):

Are you SURE you put the blame right?

`with Microsoft SMTP` - it does not indicate sendmail.

Are you SURE sendmail is accepting connection to 127.0.0.1:25 at your CentOS?

Answer (score 1):

The server runs on UTC. Your representation of the time as a user is in GMT/BST.

The 7am in the `cron` file is 0700 UTC, which right now (early October) is seen by you as 0800 BST. This corresponds to the time you receive the emails on Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

For example you could set it as follows for Pacific Standard Time.

I would try in`sendmail.cf`:

```
O TimeZoneSpec=PST8PDT
```

or in the `sendmail.mc`:

```
define(`confTIME_ZONE', `PST8PDT')dnl
```